# missing OpenCV Super Resolution in golang

Tags: opencv, go

I want to use the Super Resolution module from OpenCV in golang as it is described in this [tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-learning-based-super-resolution-with-opencv-4fd736678066)

In the C example, it uses the DnnSuperResImpl class from [dnn_superres.hpp](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/db0/dnn__superres_8hpp.html)

And the same for the Python example (dnn_superres.DnnSuperResImpl_create() from cv2.dnn_superres )

But I want to execute it from golang, I looked at [gocv](https://gocv.io/) and [go-opencv](https://github.com/go-opencv/go-opencv) but I didn't find any similar class or method.
Any clue how can I use it?

Thanks

Comment: I'm also wondering this! Did you figure out a solution?